# Batch for checking days and time

Tags: time, batch-file, days

I wrote a batch that check days and time to execute particular actions.

For the time I use this:

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:" %%a in ("%time%") do if %%a geq 7 if %%a leq 18 goto email
```

And it works pretty good.

Now I would like to ensure we execute actions only from Monday to Friday.

I think with this sentence I can have a number by day (1 = Monday and so on...):

```
wmic path win32_localtime get dayofweek
```

Someone could help me to combine them to check time and day and do action or not?

Thanks for your help.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown [here](http://www.sysnative.com/forums/windows-tips-tricks/2648-wmi-batch-script-obtain-literal-numeric-day-week.html), you could write:

```
@echo off  
set daysofweek=Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday  
for /F "skip=2 tokens=2-4 delims=," %%A in ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get DayOfWeek /Format:csv') do set daynumber=%%A  
for /F "tokens=%daynumber% delims=," %%B in ("%daysofweek%") do set day=%%B
echo day number %daynumber%
echo day %day%
```

(script copied from http://www.sysnative.com/forums/windows-tips-tricks)

Comment: Thanks for your input, now if I would like to combine both of them to check time range (from 7:00 to 18:00) then days (from Monday to Friday) and if the condition is met then goto section :email ?

Comment: You can get the hours part of the current time using a set command as follows: 'set hh=%TIME:~0,2%'